# pandas `pd.melt` multiindex column usage

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having troubles trying to write intelligible `pandas` which makes me feel like I'm missing some feature or usage (probably of the `pd.melt` method).

I have two datasets I want to combine. Both are similar:

- `time` indicating when the state changed
- `name` and `instance` a compound identity used to uniquely identify the record entry to a thing.
- Finally a single value named for the state that has changed at that time for that thing.

So an example record from each one of these dataset I want to combine would be:

1. `dict(time=0, name="a", instance=0, state=1)`
2. `dict(time=5, name="a", instance=0, location="london")`

I want to combine these two record sets into one, which have the last known `state` and `location` for each `(name, instance)` at each time.

```py
[
    dict(time=0, name="a", instance=0, state=1, location=np.nan),
    dict(time=5, name="a", instance=0, state=1, location="london"),
]
```

To get to this I currently do a combination of `pd.DataFrame.pivot_table`, `pd.DataFrame.ffill`, `pd.DataFrame.melt`, and `pd.DataFrame.reset_index`. It seems to work as intended, but it feels very cumbersome/unreadable, especially once I get into using the `pd.DataFrame.melt`.

I feel like I'm missing some usage for the `pd.DataFrame.melt` function, but I'm not really sure how to apply the documentation to the dataset with a `pd.MultiIndex` columns, that I'm working with, or if I'm missing some other `pandas` utility I should be using instead.

I'll update the question title with something more appropriate if it turns out `melt` isn't what I should be using.

Here's what I have:

```py
import pandas as pd

states = [
    dict(time=0, name="a", instance=0, state=0),
    dict(time=0, name="a", instance=1, state=0),
    dict(time=0, name="a", instance=2, state=0),
    dict(time=0, name="b", instance=1, state=0),
    dict(time=0, name="b", instance=2, state=0),
    dict(time=1, name="a", instance=1, state=1),
    dict(time=2, name="a", instance=2, state=1),
    dict(time=2, name="b", instance=1, state=1),
]

locations = [
    dict(time=0, name="a", instance=0, location="tokyo"),
    dict(time=0, name="a", instance=1, location="tokyo"),
    dict(time=0, name="a", instance=2, location="tokyo"),
    dict(time=0, name="b", instance=1, location="tokyo"),
    dict(time=0, name="b", instance=2, location="tokyo"),
    dict(time=1, name="a", instance=0, location="london"),
    dict(time=1, name="a", instance=2, location="london"),
    dict(time=1, name="b", instance=1, location="london"),
    dict(time=1, name="b", instance=2, location="london"),
    dict(time=1, name="a", instance=1, location="paris"),
    dict(time=2, name="a", instance=2, location="paris"),
    dict(time=2, name="b", instance=1, location="paris"),
]

states = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(states)
locations = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(locations)

combined = pd.concat([states, locations], axis="index")
combined = combined.pivot_table(
    index="time",
    columns=["name", "instance"],
    values=["state", "location"],
    aggfunc="last",
)
combined = combined.ffill()

ugly_melt = combined.melt(ignore_index=False)
ugly_melt = ugly_melt.rename(columns={None: "state_status"})
ugly_melt = (
    ugly_melt.reset_index()
    .pivot(
        index=["time", "name", "instance"],
        columns=["state_status"],
        values="value",
    )
    .reset_index()
)
print(ugly_melt)
```

Comment: You could use a combination of multiindex, concat and groupby to simplify your workflow. See my answer below and feel free to comment.

Comment: @freebie Can you specify the expected result? There are different results from the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `combined` look like this after `ffill`.

```py
         location                                state                    
name            a                      b             a              b     
instance        0      1       2       1       2     0    1    2    1    2
time                                                                      
0           tokyo  tokyo   tokyo   tokyo   tokyo   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1          london  paris  london  london  london   0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2          london  paris   paris   paris  london   0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0
```

There are 2 columns, `location` and `state`. You can `melt` them separately and `merge` them back.

```py
melt1 = pd.melt(combined["location"], value_name="location", ignore_index=False).reset_index()
melt2 = pd.melt(combined["state"], value_name="state", ignore_index=False).reset_index()
better_melt = melt1.merge(melt2, on=["time", "name", "instance"])
better_melt

    time name  instance location  state
0      0    a         0    tokyo    0.0
1      1    a         0   london    0.0
2      2    a         0   london    0.0
3      0    a         1    tokyo    0.0
4      1    a         1    paris    1.0
5      2    a         1    paris    1.0
6      0    a         2    tokyo    0.0
7      1    a         2   london    0.0
8      2    a         2    paris    1.0
9      0    b         1    tokyo    0.0
10     1    b         1   london    0.0
11     2    b         1    paris    1.0
12     0    b         2    tokyo    0.0
13     1    b         2   london    0.0
14     2    b         2   london    0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do a join and filter on both dataset, keeping in mind the `time` constraint (can only join on previous/current state and not future state).

This removes the need to perform forward fill `ffill()` and using joins and filter are easier to comprehend than `pd.melt` methods.

Your code for initialization

```
states = [
    dict(time=0, name="a", instance=0, state=0),
    dict(time=0, name="a", instance=1, state=0),
    dict(time=0, name="a", instance=2, state=0),
    dict(time=0, name="b", instance=1, state=0),
    dict(time=0, name="b", instance=2, state=0),
    dict(time=1, name="a", instance=1, state=1),
    dict(time=2, name="a", instance=2, state=1),
    dict(time=2, name="b", instance=1, state=1),
]

locations = [
    dict(time=0, name="a", instance=0, location="tokyo"),
    dict(time=0, name="a", instance=1, location="tokyo"),
    dict(time=0, name="a", instance=2, location="tokyo"),
    dict(time=0, name="b", instance=1, location="tokyo"),
    dict(time=0, name="b", instance=2, location="tokyo"),
    dict(time=1, name="a", instance=0, location="london"),
    dict(time=1, name="a", instance=2, location="london"),
    dict(time=1, name="b", instance=1, location="london"),
    dict(time=1, name="b", instance=2, location="london"),
    dict(time=1, name="a", instance=1, location="paris"),
    dict(time=2, name="a", instance=2, location="paris"),
    dict(time=2, name="b", instance=1, location="paris"),
]
```

**Implementation**

```
import pandas as pd

"""
Steps:
1. Convert to dataframe (Rename state time as state_time, keep location time as time)
2. Merge both dataframe together
3. Filter state time <= location time (since location uses current/previous state)
4. Filter for latest state time (since location must remember the latest state and not all previous states)
"""

# Step 1
states = pd.DataFrame(states).rename(columns={"time": "state_time"})
locations = pd.DataFrame(locations)

# Step 2
merged_df = pd.merge(locations, states, on=["name", "instance"])

# Step 3
merged_df = merged_df[merged_df["state_time"] <= merged_df["time"]]

# Step 4
merged_df = merged_df\
    .sort_values(["time", "name", "instance", "state_time"])\
    .drop_duplicates(["time", "name", "instance"], keep="last")\
    .reset_index(drop=True)\
    .drop(columns=["state_time"])
```

This results in the following `merged_df`

```
    time name  instance location  state
0      0    a         0    tokyo      0
1      0    a         1    tokyo      0
2      0    a         2    tokyo      0
3      0    b         1    tokyo      0
4      0    b         2    tokyo      0
5      1    a         0   london      0
6      1    a         1    paris      1
7      1    a         2   london      0
8      1    b         1   london      0
9      1    b         2   london      0
10     2    a         2    paris      1
11     2    b         1    paris      1
```

The length of results follows from `location` data, if you want every name-instance-location to have a time, you can do an outer join beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Datasets:

```
import pandas as pd

states = [
    dict(time=0, name="a", instance=0, state=0),
    dict(time=0, name="a", instance=1, state=0),
    dict(time=0, name="a", instance=2, state=0),
    dict(time=0, name="b", instance=1, state=0),
    dict(time=0, name="b", instance=2, state=0),
    dict(time=1, name="a", instance=1, state=1),
    dict(time=2, name="a", instance=2, state=1),
    dict(time=2, name="b", instance=1, state=1),
]

locations = [
    dict(time=0, name="a", instance=0, location="tokyo"),
    dict(time=0, name="a", instance=1, location="tokyo"),
    dict(time=0, name="a", instance=2, location="tokyo"),
    dict(time=0, name="b", instance=1, location="tokyo"),
    dict(time=0, name="b", instance=2, location="tokyo"),
    dict(time=1, name="a", instance=0, location="london"),
    dict(time=1, name="a", instance=2, location="london"),
    dict(time=1, name="b", instance=1, location="london"),
    dict(time=1, name="b", instance=2, location="london"),
    dict(time=1, name="a", instance=1, location="paris"),
    dict(time=2, name="a", instance=2, location="paris"),
    dict(time=2, name="b", instance=1, location="paris"),
]
```

It seems like time, name and instance are the levels that you use to index your data. It makes sense to add them to the index using `set_index`:

```
states = (
    pd.DataFrame.from_dict(states)
    .set_index(["time", "name", "instance"])
)
locations = (
    pd.DataFrame.from_dict(locations)
    .set_index(["time", "name", "instance"])
)
```

Once the MultiIndex is in place, you can concatenate the states and locations along the columns. This will leave some NaNs in the state column. Sort the index first so the entries are arranged by time first, then group the data based on the same name and instance, and finally perform a forward-fill.

```
combined = (
    pd.concat([states, locations], axis=1)
    .sort_index()
    .groupby(["name", "instance"])
    .ffill()
)
```

The result is slightly different from yours. What I get:

```
                   location state
time name instance      
0    a    0        tokyo    0.0
          1        tokyo    0.0
          2        tokyo    0.0
     b    1        tokyo    0.0
          2        tokyo    0.0
1    a    0        london   0.0
          1        paris    1.0
          2        london   0.0
     b    1        london   0.0
          2        london   0.0
2    a    2        paris    1.0
     b    1        paris    1.0
```

What you get:

```
state_status time name instance location state
0            0    a    0        tokyo    0.0
1            0    a    1        tokyo    0.0
2            0    a    2        tokyo    0.0
3            0    b    1        tokyo    0.0
4            0    b    2        tokyo    0.0
5            1    a    0        london   0.0
6            1    a    1        paris    1.0
7            1    a    2        london   0.0
8            1    b    1        london   0.0
9            1    b    2        london   0.0
10           2    a    0        london   0.0
11           2    a    1        paris    1.0
12           2    a    2        paris    1.0
13           2    b    1        paris    1.0
14           2    b    2        london   0.0
```

First of all, I get a MultiIndex DataFrame. If you don't like it, just `reset_index()`.
Most importantly, you get extra rows that I don't have, for example when (time, name, instance) = (2, a, 0). None of the input data has this combination of values, so that's why it's not present in my result. It is in yours because of how `pivot_table` works. It might be a desirable behaviour or not, up to you to decide.